# How to draw large amount of data on gnuplot canvas?

Tags: canvas, size, gnuplot

I have been using gnuplot for some time now and

```
set terminal pdfcairo
set output 'out.pdf'
```

has always been just enough for me. However, now I am trying to draw really a lot of data, so lines start to overlap each other (x-positions are so close to each other that lines cannot be visualised without drawing one over another). I would like to resolve this by simply making a bigger pdf. Range of x-axis would stay the same, but there would be more points to draw between ticks.

Any idea how to do it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Bigger PDF" is realized by the `size` option to `set terminal pdfcairo`, e.g. if you're looking at a 30cm x 10cm PDF:

`set terminal pdfcairo size 30cm,10cm`

From `help pdfcairo`:

> The default size for the output is 5 inches x 3 inches. The `size`
>   option  changes this to whatever the user requests. By default the X
>   and Y sizes are  taken to be in inches, but other units are possibly
>   (currently only cm).  Screen coordinates always run from 0.0 to 1.0
>   along the full length of the  plot edges as specified by the `size`
>   option.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I have tried this but forgot about inches. Thanks.